# Single-word verb for "make immutable"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

What would be a single-word verb for making something immutable (= unchanging over time or unable to be changed; generally used to describe objects in computer science)?

What I actually want to say is

> `UnmodifiableMap` is a map with immutable keys *and* values. `UnmodifiableKeySetMap` is a modified version of `UnmodifiableMap` that only ??? the keys.

Comment: Petrify, freeze, arrest, crystallize, congeal

Comment: Codify, concretize, solidify, archive, set, standardize?

Comment: Fix. "b :  to give a permanent or final form to: such as (1) :  to change into a stable compound or available form bacteria that fix nitrogen (2) :  to kill, harden, and preserve for microscopic study (3) :  to make the image of (a photographic film) permanent by removing unused salts" MW.

Comment: Immobilize.  (Reminds me of Lot's wife.)

Comment: Lock -- as in the file is locked.

Comment: Publish an official version.

Comment: ***finalize*** as in to finalize a CD-R for example.

Comment: What I actually want to say is "`UnmodifiableMap` is a map with immutable keys *and* values. `UnmodifiableKeySetMap` is a modified version of  `UnmodifiableMap` that only ??? the keys.". Would any of the above suggestions hold in this case?

Comment: I voted for Jim's suggestion, of, "finalize."  But in the programmer's context, maybe, "protect," or, "overwrite-protect," is the word that best conveys the meaning.  The essential purpose of making the value immutable would be to protect it from overwriting.

Comment: I've added your example into the text of the question, which makes it much more answerable. If you could also clarify what you mean by *keys* that would be even better (maybe that's already obvious to a computer science person, but to me it could mean the keys of a keyboard or some more abstract concept like the legend of a map).

Comment: [Adamantize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adamantium)

Comment: @1006a - "map" here does not mean a geographic map, but some mapping of keys to values (in the sense of mathematical functions that maps numbers to other numbers, or a dictionary that maps words to their meannings). I'm trying to describe a kind of map that holds a pre-set set of unmodifieable keys (entries), where only the values might change.

Comment: Why is it important that it *makes* keys immutable rather than *has* immutable keys?

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "locks".  Only the keys are locked in the second case.

Comment: OK, thanks. Both "lock" and "has only immutable" can work for me.

Comment: I support "fix."  @PhilSweet why don't you write an answer?

Comment: I was pleased with the coinage immutabilize, but then I realized after using a search engine that other people have used this monstrosity. :(

Answer (score 2):

"Stabilize" could fit, but at a less forceful meaning than immutable.
Or "Freeze," which implies no further change or movement.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a widely recognized verb form. I use "immutablize", because I think the majority of readers will understand the intent.

I wish "immute" was an option, but it's already a word that means "to change" (which seems backwards, but I'm not an etymologist).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use:

**ascribe**
[uh-skrahyb]
verb (used with object)

1. to credit or assign, as to a cause or source; attribute; impute
2. to attribute or think of as belonging, as a quality or characteristic

Or

**affix**
[uh-fiks]
verb (used with object)

1. to fasten, join, or attach (usually followed by to)
2. to put or add on; append

*Definitions taken from dictionary.com